Error: Property 'all' does not exist on type 'ticket' account in Anchor program
I'm working on a Solana program using Anchor ("^0.30.1") and encountered an error while trying to fetch accounts with the all method. I want to retrieve all tickets for a specific lotteryId and filter them by the user's public key. However, I'm receiving the following TypeScript error:
Property 'all' does not exist on type '{ fetch: (address: PublicKey) => Promise<TicketAccount>; }'.ts(2339)

Here’s the relevant part of my code:
if (!wallet?.publicKey) return;

const userTickets = await program.account.ticket.all([
  {
    memcmp: {
      bytes: bs58.encode(
        new BN(lotteryId).toArrayLike(Buffer, "le", 4)
      ),
      offset: 12,
    },
  },
  {
    memcmp: {
      bytes: wallet.publicKey.toBase58(),
      offset: 16,
    },
  },
]);

How can I resolve this error? Does the all() method need additional setup, or should I use another approach for filtering accounts? Is there a better way to apply memcmp for on-chain filtering of accounts?
Thanks in advance :)

based on the error, it looks like you might have defined the account as TicketAccount rather than just Ticket. If that's the case, you might try program.account.ticketAccount.all(...
